# how to replace a value with javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

I have the following code:

```
var adUnitBids = [
{
    bidder: '',
    params: {
       placementId: 'var'
    }

},
```

and I want to replace the string variable with a new value, through Javascript or PHP (not in jQuery or AJAX, just Javascript or PHP only).

I made this:

```
var div = document.querySelector("selector[placementId='var']");
```

i dont know how to continue. Really, i dont know if var above will works.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You have a javascript variable `adUnitBids` with an array of objects, so you might get the first item from the array using 0 as the index and update the value of the object: `adUnitBids[0].params.placementId = "test";` [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) takes a valid CSS selector string.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing html and javascript. Your `var` bit looks like you're attempting to grab an html value. Can you share your html code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var adUnitBids = [{
  bidder: '',
  params: {
    placementId: 'var'
  }
}];

adUnitBids[0].params.placementId = 'rav';

console.log(adUnitBids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable, from what I can tell, is just a JSON array. You can simply do something like:

```
adUnitBids[0].params.placementId = 'JuicyFruit';
```

Example:

```js
var adUnitBids = [
{
    bidder: '',
    params: {
       placementId: 'var'
    }

}]

adUnitBids[0].params.placementId = 'JuicyFruit';

console.log(adUnitBids);
```

Your issue is you were trying to access the variable as if it were an html element as opposed to a json object.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i did what you explained and works but not really in the environment it´s run, since it´s run on programmatsic, lot of iframes and request are made, and make it difficult to succeed. If i paste it inside mi html directly it works. But inside iframes from iframes from iframes and lot of requests inside (as programmatic works) well, nothing happens. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you have an array of objects with unknown length.
You can update it with both javascript or PHP, depending where that array is, in the browser or in the server.
If that code is in the browser, you can update it with javascript.

In javascript, arrays have positions/indexes and you need to know witch position you need to update.

If you need to update a specific position in the array, you can access it with the index.

```
adUnitBids[0].params.placementId = 'new value';
```

Note that adUnitBids[0] will point to the index 0 of the array.

If you need to update the values of the hole array, you can use forEach

```
adUnitBids.forEach(function(item){
   item.params.placementId = 'new value';
})
```